# .NET library/method to Fix and URL encode spaces correctly

Tags: .net, regex, url-rewriting

**NOTE**: This only applies to "href" attribute values.

1, I need a way to separate the protocol (ftp, http, https, etc) and domain extension (.net, .com, .org, .shop, etc) from the path in C#
2, DELETE all spaces in the protocol.
3, DELETE all spaces in the domain extension
4, DELETE spaces to the right and left of the path
5, Replace spaces WITHIN the path with %20
**Source**: href=" somedomain.co m/  my folder/my page.  html" 
**Output**: href="somedomain.com/my%20folder/my%20page.html"
**Source**: href="http[s]://somedomain.com/my folder/"
**Output**: href="http[s]://somedomain.com/my%20folder/"
**Source**: href="ht tp[s]: //www .somedomain.  co m/my folder/ "
**Output**: href="http[s]://somedomain.com/my%20folder/"
**NOTE**: space in "ht tp", after colon ": //", after the period and within the domain extension".  co m"
**Source**: href=" somedomain. com/my folder/ "
**Output**: href="somedomain.com/my%20folder/"

I'm not interested in encoding anything else. All I want to do is remove **unnecessary** spaces and encode spaces in the path to make the URL valid. Thus the following libraries are of no use:

```
Uri.EscapeDataString
HttpUtility.UrlEncode
Uri.EscapeUriString
HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode
```

Comment: I don't think such a method exist. The problem is, there is not always an obvious way how to "fix" broken URL strings like yours, e.g. why are the spaces after m/ in your second example removed and the next one preserved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following regex should do it for you:

```
(?<=[/.]|^([^/]|//)*)\s+|\s+(?=[/.])
```

Replacing that with `""` (empty string) in the URLs removes all unwanted spaces. Then simply replace the remaining spaces with `%20`.

Regex explanation:

It consists of two alternations:

1. `(?<=[/.]|^([^/]|//)*)\s+`
2. `\s+(?=[/.])`

The second one simply matches all spaces following a path part - all spaces before a `/` or a `.`.

- `\s+` all spaces
- `(?=[/.])` look ahead matching a `/` or a `.`.

The first one is a bit more complicated. It matches all spaces (the ending `\s+`) preceded by a match to the positive look behind `(?<=[/.]|^([^/]|//)*)`.

This look behind - `(?<=[/.]|^([^/]|//)*)` - consists of two alternations where the first part - `[/.]` - simply matches a `/` or a `.`.

The second part - `^([^/]|//)*` - matches everything in the URL, from the start of the line (`^`), that **isn't a single** `/`. (The alternation with `//` makes the double slash in `http://` pass.)

What this means in short is that it matches all spaces before the first **single** slash in the URL. Together with the previously explained alternation the complete regex thus matches **all unwanted spaces**.

So the remaining spaces should simply be replaced with `%20` :)

Illustration of how to fix the spaces using C#:

```
Regex.Replace(sURL, @"(?<=/|^([^/]|//)*)\s+|\s+(?=/)", "").Replace(" ", "%20")
```

And if I understand you correctly you also want to identify the protocols, if any (requirement 1). So after the previous operation has been done, simply matching with `^\w+(?=://)` should get you those. (Match all the characters from the beginning of the line up to `://`.)

Regarding the top domain, the approach is the same - extract it afterwards. But we use a part from the first regex to make sure we only get the top domain and not file extension or such. The regex `(?<=[/.]|^([^/]|//)*)\w+(?=(/|$))` will only match characters before a first single `/` using the the look behind explained earlier. But this time, instead of spaces, we match word characters - `\w`, up to a `/` or line termination (`$`). That gives us the top domain.

[Check it out at ideone](https://ideone.com/n0wtXj).

Sorry for the garbled URL's - It's ideone doing it and don't know how to "undo" that, but here's the original code:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
    public static string CleanURL(string sURL, out string sProtocol, out string sTopDomain)
    {
        string sCleanURL = Regex.Replace(sURL, @"(?<=[/.]|^([^/]|//)*)\s+|\s+(?=[/.])", "").Replace(" ", "%20");
        sProtocol = Regex.Match(sCleanURL, @"^\w+(?=://)").Value;
        sTopDomain = Regex.Match(sCleanURL, @"(?<=[/.]|^([^/]|//)*)\w+(?=(/|$))").Value;

        return sCleanURL;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        string[] listURL = {
            " somed omain.co m/  my folder/my page.  html",
            "http://somedomain.info/my folder  /",
            "https://somedomain.com/my folder/",
            "ht tp: //www .somedomain.  co m/my folder/ ",
            "ht tps: //www .somedomain.  in fo/my folder/ ",
            " somedomain. com/my folder/ ",
            "ht tp: //www .somedomain.  co m/my folder/ sub.folder  / directory  /",
            "ht tps: //www .somedomain.  in fo/my folder/ ",
            " somedomain. com/my folder/ ",
            " somedomain. tv "
            };

        // Write header
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Protocol   Top domain   URL\n"));
        foreach(string sURL in listURL)
        {
            string sCleanURL, sProtocol, sTopDomain;

            sCleanURL = CleanURL( sURL, out sProtocol, out sTopDomain);

            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0,-9}  {1,-11}  {2} ", sProtocol, sTopDomain, sCleanURL));
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Protocol   Top domain   URL

           com          somedomain.com/my%20folder/my%20page.html 
http       info         http://somedomain.info/my%20folder/ 
https      com          https://somedomain.com/my%20folder/ 
http       com          http://www.somedomain.com/my%20folder/ 
https      info         https://www.somedomain.info/my%20folder/ 
           com          somedomain.com/my%20folder/ 
http       com          http://www.somedomain.com/my%20folder/sub.folder/directory/ 
https      info         https://www.somedomain.info/my%20folder/ 
           com          somedomain.com/my%20folder/ 
           tv           somedomain.tv
```

Answer (score 1):

**Proposed solution:**

1. `split` the `string` in **2 parts** with `href=\"((?:.*//.*?/)|.*?/)` or similar regex;
2. Replace `spaces` with `nothing` on the **1st part**;
3. Replace `spaces` with `%20` on the **2nd part**;

i.e.:

```
using System;
using  System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{


    public static void Main()
    {
        string subject = "href=\" somedomain.co m/  my folder/my page.  html\"";
        Console.Write(replaceMe(subject)  + "\n") ;


        subject = "href=\"http[s]://somedomain.com/my folder/\"";
        Console.Write(replaceMe(subject) + "\n" );


        subject = "href=\"ht tp[s]: //www .somedomain.  co m/my folder/ \"";
        Console.Write(replaceMe(subject) + "\n" );


        subject = "href=\" somedomain. com/my folder/ \"";
        Console.Write(replaceMe(subject) + "\n" );
    }


    public static string replaceMe(string subject){

        subject = Regex.Replace(subject, " \"|\" ", "\"");
        string[] splitArray = Regex.Split(subject, "href=\"((?:.*//.*?/)|.*?/)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        string part_a = Regex.Replace(splitArray[1], @"\s+", "");
        string part_b = Regex.Replace(splitArray[2], @"\s", "%20");
        return ("href=\"" + part_a  +  part_b );    
    }
}
```

---

**Output:**

```
href="somedomain.com/%20%20my%20folder/my%20page.%20%20html"
href="http[s]://somedomain.com/my%20folder/"
href="http[s]://www.somedomain.com/my%20folder/"
href="somedomain.com/my%20folder/"
```

---

[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QdeTTI)

PS: I'm **not** a `.NET` expert and I'm sure the `regex` and demo code **can (should) be improved** (e.g.: `try/catch` blocks).

Comment: Looks like your answer is good. I'm just wondering if the OP wanted this behaviour with `http[s]`, or maybe was just indicating that it should work with both `http` and `https`. Small thing to clarify with @user1932634

Comment: Thank you. We'll have to wait for  clarification.

Comment: This won't do. You're missing requirement 4 (if I interpret it correctly from the examples). The spaces in the beginning or end of **any** part of the path should be removed. See the "my folder" part in OP's first example.

Comment: @PedroLobito Yes. Any common protocol found in (x)HTML i.e. (ftp, http, https, etc). It's noted in the question

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to write any code for you, but I could write it in C# if needed.

So, this is the regex to get what you need.

Find:  `(?m)^(.+?)((?>//?)(?<!:\s*/\s*/).*?)\s*$`
Replacement:
Concatenate - *Strip spaces from group 1* + *Replace spaces with `%20` in group*  2

Demo: [Here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3fm%29%5e%28.%2b%3f%29%28%28%3f%3e%2f%2f%3f%29%28%3f%3c!%3a%5cs*%2f%5cs*%2f%29.*%3f%29%5cs*%24&i=+somedomain.co+m%2f++my+folder%2fmy+page.++html%0d%0ahttp%5bs%5d%3a%2f%2fsomedomain.com%2fmy+folder%2f%0d%0aht+tp%5bs%5d%3a+%2f%2fwww+.somedomain.++co+m%2fmy+folder%2f+%0d%0a+somedomain.+com%2fmy+folder%2f+)

Readable / Explained

```
 (?m)                          # Multiline mode
 ^                             # BOL
 ( .+? )                       # (1), Domain, required
 (                             # (2 start), Directory, optional
      (?> //? )                     # Atomic Start /
      (?<! : \s* / \s* / )          # Cannot be :// <--
      .*? 
 )                             # (2 end)
 \s*                           # Trim trailing whitespace
 $                             # EOL
```